# How to center text below image in lightbox gallery?

Tags: php, html, css, lightbox

I am trying to center the text below each image on [this site](http://www.germanwarletters.com/slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter11IntotheAbyss) but I am running into issues.

Every time I try to put an image in a `div` it breaks the lightbox gallery.

Here is my photo gallery generation code:

```
<?php
class struct
{
    function imageDisplayGallery($img_folder_path)
    {
        //lists all files with _thumbs in folder. stores letter number as key in array called $numbers, and thumbnail as value
        $numbers=array();
        foreach(glob("$img_folder_path*/*_thumb.jpg") as $thumb)
        {
            $thumb=str_replace("%2F","/",urlencode($thumb));
            $thumb=str_replace("+"," ",$thumb);
            $int=explode("/",$thumb)[3].explode("/",$thumb)[4];
            $int=str_replace("Letter %23","",$int);
            $int=str_replace("_thumb.jpg","",$int);
            $numbers[$int]=$thumb;
        }

        //generate code to display image and thumb
            foreach($numbers as $key => $thumb)
        {
            $full=str_replace("_thumb","",$thumb);
            echo '<a href="',$full,'" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="',$thumb,'" /></a>';
            echo "$key";
        }
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You would need to change the HTML for this - you need wrappers for image + text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this set-up for each item. It uses CSS flex layout to arrange the image and text in a column. The text is wrapped in a `span` element and placed inside the anchor element.

```css
a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="http://www.germanwarletters.com/img/letter_images/Chapter11IntotheAbyss/Letter%20%23%20445/A_thumb.jpg" /><span>445A</span></a>
<a href="#" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="http://www.germanwarletters.com/img/letter_images/Chapter11IntotheAbyss/Letter%20%23%20445/A_thumb.jpg" /><span>445A</span></a>
<a href="#" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="http://www.germanwarletters.com/img/letter_images/Chapter11IntotheAbyss/Letter%20%23%20445/A_thumb.jpg" /><span>445A</span></a>
<a href="#" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="http://www.germanwarletters.com/img/letter_images/Chapter11IntotheAbyss/Letter%20%23%20445/A_thumb.jpg" /><span>445A</span></a>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0q5etmka/)

Comment: I tried adding the style to my gallery class, and adding the span, but it didnt quite work as expected. I'm not sure how to debug it though. Any idea what Im doing wrong? The link in my post has my attempt at following your instructions

Comment: The `span` has to be inside the `a` element.